# How do I make my project see library project repository

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have a 'master project' which uses two third party libraries which I have forked on github and altered as separate projects locally.

My 'master project' correctly imports the library projects, however one of those projects (which I added some time ago) includes a direct reference to the local repository for the library, so I can change which branch I use but the second library repository is not listed.

How can I add the repo for the second library in the same way in Android Studio?

*Note: The library which is shown may be shown as a side effect because of the way it was added in a different manner originally (direct from base repo on github before I forked it). It's gradle file contained an `ext {}` section with repo information. Trying to copy the same into the other project did not help*

*Note: Adding the remote repo url using <kbd>VCS</kbd> -> <kbd>Git</kbd> -> <kbd>Remotes</kbd> also did not work, as this tries to add it as a source repo for the main modules*

[image]